# How can I set default CPU Affinity for all the daemons in systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd

I need to set the default CPU affinity for all the daemons managed by systemd, except a specific service.

Setting service's CPU affinity at `/etc/systemd/system/myname.service.d/scheduler.conf` works just fine, so I guessed I could set my service affinity to, say, cores 2-11, and let the rest of the system to live with cores 0-1.

It seems I can't.

I tried `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/default.conf` and even changed `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

All the daemons (except my one) still start with all the CPUs allowed.

It seems too much hassle to setup an override `/etc/systemd/system/*.service.d` configuration file for each other system service.

The systemd version is 215 (from Debian Jessie)

Update: I revisited `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and found that I misspelled the CPU cores list. I experimented a bit more and found that, although I can setup default CPU Affinity in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, the setting in `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I would prefer to keep this setting in `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/scheduler.conf` as the whole fleet is managed by ansible. I found a couple of examples at github with the section (`[Manager]`) line absent, but this doesn't work for me, too. Documentation clearly mention `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d`. What do I miss?

Comment: I don't have a way to test this, but did you check CPUAffinity parameter in /etc/systemd/system.conf, that should configure default cpuaffinity for init process and thus all other daemons

Comment: Well, I tried it first by misspeeled the CPU list. This does solve the issue indeed but it's a bit inconvenient as all the servers are managed by ansible and placing configuration file into `system.conf.d` is much better that changing system default file

Answer (score 3):

Ok, apparently the v215 from Jessie doesn't support `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d` at all (see `src/core/main.c:parse_config_file`).

Pity.

The case is closed, though.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. FWIW, this was introduced in v228